# Call Controller method from view in EXTJS 4 MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am new to EXTJS 4 MVC architecture . I have one function in controller which i want to call from my view. How can i call that function?

Comment: You should be calling the function from your controller not your view. i.e all your logic should be in the controller and not in the view. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message: `YourApp.fireEvent('my_event', options)` and listen it inside of your controller. But it's not right.

If you're using as you're talking **mvc** you should not write code in view. (Note: There may be a code, for example column renderer code, not business logic). View should be just a component group. To create component event listener use **control** method of Ext.app.Controller.

Comment: Passing an event to the controller from the view is the right way. How else do you communicate betweern view and controller?

Comment: As i already wrote: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control

Comment: Ok. I get your point of view. That happens when you want to talk with your own controller. Otherwise you fire event on the app or a special bus event. Firing events is the right way. Calling directly a controller from a view is bad way.

Comment: I can't understand: what do you mean "your own controller"? 
why do you need to fire event from view, write additional code, if you can handle it from controller directly by controlling xtype?
Few controllers can handle the events from one view, there is no problem.

Comment: Lets say I have an workspace with toolbar and a grid. A "delete button" on the toolbar and "delete item" in  a right click menu will do same thing (more or less). The toolbar and the grid will have different controllers.

Comment: Send the message from one controller to another. i think, it's convenient to contain logic in controller, and view should be just a view, without logic. I do so. You can do another way. Ext js is flexible, that's good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:
You can put your controller as a global variable in your app.js like so:

```
Ext.define('MySharedData', {
    my_Controller:Object

});
```

In your controller:

```
MySharedData.my_Controller=this.getController('<ControllerfolderPath>.controllerName');
```

then call the function that you want, from your view:

```
 MySharedData.my_Controller.my_Function();
```